# php - Regular expression question

Tags: php, string, passwords

I want to generate a random password that has the following pattern:

**Capital, small, number, dash, capital, small, number, special charachter.**

Example:

```
Ab1-Cd2$
```

I have put all the special characters in an array that I randomly pick, so I have that part figured out. But I have no clue of how to do the other part. Any suggestion?

Comment: Why does this require a regex?

Comment: @Mchl The other part as in capital, small, number.  And about the other part: I don't know exactly, thought that would be the best solution.

Comment: If the password is randomly generated, you don't require regex, as the password should be already acceptable to be used, should't it?

Comment: the other part is to check such a password?

Comment: its not random if you dictate the pattern, and its also less secure by doing so

Comment: Fix your title please. This does not describe anything. Every post is a question, and the technologies are already in the tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is not the best way, but this will work

```
<?php

    $capital    = range ('A','Z');
    $small      = range ('a','z');
    $number     = range ('0','9');
    $special    = array ("#","$","@");

    $password   =   $capital[array_rand($capital)] . 
                    $small[array_rand($small)] . 
                    $number[array_rand($number)] . 
                    "-" . 
                    $capital[array_rand($capital)] . 
                    $small[array_rand($small)] . 
                    $number[array_rand($number)] . 
                    $special[array_rand($special)];

    print $password;
```

You can read about the functions i used here

[array_rand](http://php.net/array_rand)

[range](http://in.php.net/range)

Will produce results like:

```
Tg8-Im1$
Yj3-Xl3@
Cr1-Lv1@
```

which i guess is your requirement

Please let me know if you want any more help on this.

Comment: Got it, thanks. But array_rand didnt work for me, it only returned the position as an integer. I went with, for example, `rand(0,25)`.

Comment: Yes, `array_rand` will only return you the position of a random integer. thats why we put it as a key to the same array so that it will return a random value. I tried running that script and it worked for me. Again since we already know the number of elements avilable, your variation is also good. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `chr()` together with a random ascii value out of the range of A-Z, a-b, 0-9.

chr here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php

ASCII table here: http://www.asciitable.com/

Example: a-z is from 97 to 122.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use *regex* here. You need an array with values of all possible chars that may appear in the password. Then you simply loop over that array and take random key from it.

```
$chars = array('a', 'b', 'c'); // For example.
$length = 6;

$password = '';
$count = count($chars) - 1;
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
    $password .= $chars[mt_rand(0, $count)];
}

echo $password;
```

**Edit:**

There's a neat trick if you need values that are somehow *in range*. You can use [range()](http://php.net/range) function.

For example, here are that function, plus, [chr()](http://php.net/chr) function to get ASCII chars (from 0x20 to 0x7E).

```
$chars = range(chr(32), chr(126));
```